# Most frequent words from text excluding words that are of certain length

Tags: python, word-count

I'm having I'm having trouble with finding a solution to my problem, maybe someone will be able to help. I have a poem and I'm able to display the most common words, although I want all strings that are less than 5 characters long to not be displayed in my lets say top 20 most common list.

```
import collections

import re

words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('some_poem.txt').read().lower())
most_common = collections.Counter(words).most_common(20)


print(most_common)
```

Is there a short and clean way to add such functionality? To not display strings that are 5 characters or less? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "shorter than 5" you mean "less than 5 characters long" you can just change your regex to not return those words in the first place, using `{5,}` (five or more) instead of `+` (one or more):

```
words = re.findall(r'\w{5,}', open('some_poem.txt').read().lower())
```

---

The following is *not* what you asked for, but depending on what you really want, it might be more useful, to get a `set` of [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) and filter those from the list of words, since there may very well be "relevant" words with fewer than five letters, and irrelevant ones with more.

```
stop_words = set("a,able,about,across,...,you,your".split(","))
words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('some_poem.txt').read().lower())
words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
```

Also, just for completeness, as noted in comments, you should make it a habit to use `with` to open files to make sure they are properly closed afterwards.

```
with open('some_poem.txt') as f:
    words = re.findall(r'\w{5,}', f.read().lower())
```

Comment: Amazing! really simple and super effective. Thanks a lot. Really appriciate it. Regarding stop words, the poem that I'm working on is in a foreign language. It's easier in that given language to just remove words that are less than 5 characters long, I've worded the question wrong. My bad.

Comment: When you pass `open(file)` to a function, is the opening and closing handled safely and is the handle closed? Or does it just go out of scope and disappear? When considering the amount of weight people place on using `with open`, this seems a bit counterintuitive to me as far as design goes

Comment: I've just seen it used in a few places and was genuinely curious

Answer (score 2):

A `Counter` is just a dictionary, so we can use a dict comprehension to filter the results we need:

```
{ k: v for k, v in most_common.items() if v > 5 }
```